# Lists in "launch forms in a dialog" set to "yes"

Tags: sharepoint-online

The Lists are launching everywhere in a Dialog, except in the "Web Form Part".
Unfortunately I am working in a Company with SharePoint Online, but not with modern lists.
Could anyone help me to change the Settings, that my lists also open in a dialog form from the Web Form Part ?

Comment: what is "web form part"? could you provide a screenshot about it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for asking. If You are on a list, you have the possibility to modify the web parts in the forms associated with this list. The Button called "Form Web Parts".
I have attached my example, where in the list part of the Web Form, the Dialog Navigation is missing and in the library Part of the Web Form, the Dialog Navigation is doing. (->Same List in the upper and down area).

[image]